# Strange window background for textured window in Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am implementing a Mac OS X application in Mac OS 10.6 (XCode 3.2) I am using several textured windows. The texture look is nice in all OS versions except Mac OS X 10.8: in some windows, the dark gray color of the texture makes a sudden change to a much lighter gray color in the middle of the window height (so it seems like the window is cut in two). I've been looking around and could not find any answer. Do you know how to solve this?

[Two color background in textured 10.8 window http://www.aldoilsant.com/settings.png](http://www.aldoilsant.com/settings.png)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the setting for the window's Content Border. Set the content border to "none" or another value appropriate for your app.

In Xcode's interface builder, select the window. Choose the Size Inspector, then adjust the "Content Border".

[image]